# Solving $-\left(\frac{5}{x-1}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am not familiar with equations, here I am trying to find the value of $x$ in this equation so, what should I do?
$$-\bigg(\dfrac{5}{x-1}\bigg)=\dfrac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Hint: $x-1=-10$

Answer (score 3):

Even though other answers are already posted, I just want to remind you that since you want to find $x$, your priority should be leaving it alone. Step by step, it is like this:

$$-\dfrac{5}{x-1}=\dfrac{1}{2}$$

$$-5 =\dfrac{x-1}{2}$$

$$-10=x-1$$

$$-9=x$$

Answer (score 2):

$-\bigg(\dfrac{5}{x-1}\bigg)=\dfrac{1}{2}$

Multiply both sides by -$1$

$\bigg(\dfrac{5}{x-1}\bigg)=-\dfrac{1}{2}$

Cross multiply-

$x-1=-10$

$x=-10+1$

$x=-9$

there’s your answer.

Try doing these on your own, these should be very easy for you.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides of the equation by $-2(x-1)$ to obtain a more trivial equation.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is not the recommended way to go, you can solve it "by inspection".

For the two members to be equal, you need the denominator of the left fraction to be the double of $5$ with a negative sign. Hence $x-1=-10$, or $x=-9$.

---

A more orthodoxical way is by reducing the two fractions to the same denominator $2(x-1)$, noting that $x-1=0$ is not allowed. You get

$$-\frac{10}{2(x-1)}=\frac{x-1}{2(x-1)}.$$  and you are nearly done.

Answer (score 1):

-(5/X-1) = 1/2

Taking reciprocal and changing signs , (X-1)/5 = -2

$X-1 = -10$ => $X = -9$